# PostgreSQL drop constraint with unknown name

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, psql

I have an SQL script that needs to drop several constraints and restore them at the end, but the constraint names are auto-generated and will be different each time the script is run.

I know how to get the constraint name from the table names, but it doesn't seem possible to use this information in the drop statement.

```
select conname from pg_constraint where
   conrelid = (select oid from pg_class where relname='table name')
   and confrelid = (select oid from pg_class where relname='reference table');
```

`alter table something drop constraint (some subquery)` is a syntax error.

Ideally I would like to get the constraint name and store it in a variable, but it doesn't seem that Postgres supports that and I can't make it work with psql `\set`.

Is this even possible?

Comment: You would *at least* need dynamic SQL to do this. Object names (tablenames,columnnames,etc) can Never be specified as variables (or subqueries) without first constructing the query (in a string) and then executing that. Using sed/awk to generate the "DROP xxx" lines in a file, and piping that file through psql could be a workaround. It will still be hard to maintain some "atomicity" (But DDL's are always difficult in that respect)

Comment: @wildplasser okay, I thought maybe psql would have some functionality to do that. Otherwise, you can just put your comment as answer.

Comment: I am not that handy with dynamic query building (I actually *hate* it) Others will probably fill it in.

Comment: Filling in the dynamic stuff ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To dynamically drop & recreate a foreign key constraint, you could wrap it all in a function or use the [`DO`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-do.html) command:

```
DO
$body$
DECLARE
   _con text := (
      SELECT quote_ident(conname)
      FROM   pg_constraint
      WHERE  conrelid = 'myschema.mytable'::regclass
      AND    confrelid = 'myschema.myreftable'::regclass
      LIMIT 1 -- there could be multiple fk constraints. Deal with it ...
      );

BEGIN
   EXECUTE '
      ALTER TABLE wuchtel12.bet DROP CONSTRAINT ' || _con;

   -- do stuff here

   EXECUTE '
      ALTER TABLE myschema.mytable
      ADD CONSTRAINT ' || _con || ' FOREIGN KEY (col)
      REFERENCES myschema.myreftable (col)';
END
$body$
```

You must own the table to use `ALTER TABLE`.
Else you can [create a function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html) with `LANGUAGE plpgsql SECURITY DEFINER` (using the same body) and

```
ALTER FUNCTION foo() OWNER TO postgres;
```

`postgres` being a superuser here - or the owner of the table.
But be sure to know what [the manual has to say about security](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html#SQL-CREATEFUNCTION-SECURITY).

[The manual also has more on dynamic commands.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)

Answer (score 0):

You can use stored procedure also.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.p_costraint()
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$
DECLARE _constrint text;
begin
-- for dynamic change the constraint. 
    _constrint := (
      SELECT quote_ident(conname)
      FROM   pg_constraint
        WHERE  conrelid = 'test.contacts'::regclass
        AND    confrelid = 'test.customers'::regclass
      LIMIT 1 -- there could be multiple fk constraints. Deal with it ...
      );
    _constrint := _constrint || 'test';
    EXECUTE '
      ALTER TABLE test.contacts
      ADD CONSTRAINT ' || _constrint || ' FOREIGN KEY (customer_id)
      REFERENCES test.customers (customer_id)';
    RAISE NOTICE 'hello, world!';
end
$procedure$;
```

In here. constraint name is used as a text variable.
You can just call it: `call public.p_costraint();`
It will return :

```
NOTICE:  hello, world!
CALL
```