# Find the referenced table name using table, field and schema name

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, constraints

I have a requirement where I need to find the referenced table name (Primary key table name) by a particular field in a table (Foreign key table) using this field name, table name (where this field resides) and the schema name (where the table and thereby the field resides)

For example:

```
Schema1.TableA
  Id (Integer, PK)  
  Name varchar


Schema2.TableB
  Id (integer, PK)  
  A_Id (integer, FK referencing TableA.Id)  
  Name varchar
```

I need to pass `A_Id`, `TableB` and `Schema2` to a function and get `Schema1.TableA` as result.

I am using Postgres 8.3.

Comment: I think you need to [query the information_schema.key_column_usage table](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/infoschema-key-column-usage.html). That schema isn't in your path, so start with something like `select * from information_schema.key_column_usage;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need this to be portable to another RDBMS (or another major Postgres version) it is faster and simpler to use the catalog tables in `pg_catalog` instead of the standard information schema:

```sql
SELECT c.confrelid::regclass::text AS referenced_table
     , c.conname AS fk_name
     , pg_get_constraintdef(c.oid) AS fk_definition
FROM   pg_attribute a 
JOIN   pg_constraint c ON (c.conrelid, c.conkey[1]) = (a.attrelid, a.attnum)
WHERE  a.attrelid = '"Schema2"."TableB"'::regclass   -- table name
AND    a.attname  = 'A_Id'                           -- column name  
AND    c.contype  = 'f'
ORDER  BY referenced_table, c.contype DESC;
```

Returns:

| referenced_table | fk_name | fk_definition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Schema1.TableA | b1_fkey | FOREIGN KEY ("B_id") REFERENCES "Schema1"."TableA"("A_id") |

You only asked for the first column. I added two columns for context.

This returns *all* referenced tables by all foreign keys involving the given column name - including FK constraints on multiple columns.

The name is automatically schema-qualified if necessary according to the current [`search_path`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC_SEARCH_PATH). It is also double-quoted automatically where needed.

Check out details of [`pg_constraint`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-constraint.html) and [`pg_attribute`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-attribute.html) in the manual. More about [object identifier types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html), too.

Related:

- [PostgreSQL drop constraint with unknown name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395466/postgresql-drop-constraint-with-unknown-name/12396684#12396684)
- [Retrieving all PK and FK](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/37068/3684)