# How to check if a field is FK in another table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table in `Postgesql`:

```
CREATE TABLE customers
(
  customerid integer NOT NULL,
  customerid2 text NOT NULL,
  ....
)
```

How can I check if `customerid2` is used as FK in other tables?
suppose I will drop this column, before it execute the actual drop - it checks who uses it. How do I perform that check manualy?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[postgresql]+find+foreign+keys

Comment: Didn't find anything that works there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18383810/find-referenced-fields-of-foreign-key-constraint this was promiseing but it doesn't work.