# Change primary key from simple to composite with new column

Tags: sql, postgresql, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I am trying to change the primary key of one of my tables from a simple to a composite key, where the composite should be composed of the old pk column and a newly created one.

I followed along this answer from a very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27832197/1948454

It almost works, except that there is no value set in the dependant table for the new column.

Here's the situation:

Suppose I have a table for a catalog, and a table for catalog entries. Before:

```
-- DDL Catalog

CREATE TABLE public.Catalog (
    name_ VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    foo_ VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Catalog_pkey PRIMARY KEY (name_)
);

-- DDL CatalogEntry

CREATE TABLE public.CatalogEntry (
    pricekey_ VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    pricekeyroot_ VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    catalog_name_ VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    bar_ VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT CatalogEntry_pkey PRIMARY KEY (pricekey_, pricekeyroot_)
);    

-- public.CatalogEntry FOREIGN KEYs

ALTER TABLE public.CatalogEntry ADD CONSTRAINT CatalogEntry_catalog_name__fkey FOREIGN KEY (catalog_name_) REFERENCES Catalog(name_) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

So `CatalogEntry.catalog_name` references to `Catalog.name_`.

Now I need to add another column `version_` to the `Catalog` table, indicating a version of some catalog. This means I will have to create a new composite pk composed of `name_` and `version_`. Here's my script:

```
-- UPDATE script

-- add the new version column and set all values to default of 1
ALTER TABLE Catalog ADD version_ INTEGER;
UPDATE Catalog SET version_ = 1;
ALTER TABLE Catalog ALTER column version_ SET not null;

-- update primary key and foreign key
BEGIN;
-- first, drop fkey constraint on CatalogEntry
ALTER TABLE CatalogEntry DROP CONSTRAINT CatalogEntry_catalog_name__fkey;
-- then, update Catalog primary key
ALTER TABLE Catalog DROP CONSTRAINT Catalog_pkey,
    ADD CONSTRAINT Catalog_uni_name UNIQUE (name_),
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (name_, version_);
-- now add new foreign key again to CatalogEntry
ALTER TABLE CatalogEntry ADD catalog_version_ INTEGER;
ALTER TABLE CatalogEntry 
    ADD CONSTRAINT CatalogEntry_catalog_name__catalog__fkey FOREIGN KEY (catalog_name_, catalog_version_) 
        references Catalog(name_, version_ ) ON DELETE CASCADE;
COMMIT;

-- finally, remove unique constraint on name since it is not needed anymore
ALTER TABLE Catalog DROP CONSTRAINT Catalog_uni_name;
```

After performing these steps, the primary and foreign key appear to be set correctly - but the value of `CatalogEntry.catalog_version_` is null. The corresponding value of `Catalog.version_` is set correctly to 1.

Where is my mistake? Do I also have to set `CatalogEntry.catalog_version_` manually to 1? I would have assumed that it would be set automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `CatalogEntry.catalog_version_` doesn't magically get set just because you define a foreign key constraint.

What effectively happened is that *no* row in `CatalogEntry` references a row in `Catalog`. The reason is that the default for foreign key constraints is `MATCH SIMPLE`, see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html):

> `MATCH SIMPLE` allows any of the foreign key columns to be null; if any of them are null, the row is not required to have a match in the referenced table.

You should create the foreign key constraint as `MATCH FULL` so that either all or none of the columns must be NULL. Then you would have received an error creating the foreign key.

Solution: update `CatalogEntry` and set the column to 1 there as well, then define the foreign key with `MATCH FULL`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation and solution.