# How to drop constraint on postgers?

Tags: postgresql, ddl

I have created a constraint this way:

```
ALTER TABLE  varaus  ADD FOREIGN KEY ( varaus_id ) REFERENCES  kayttaja  ( id );
```

But when trying to drop it:

```
ALTER TABLE varaus DROP CONSTRAINT varaus_id;
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR:  constraint "varaus_id" of relation "varaus" does not exist
```

I have also tried:

```
ALTER TABLE varaus DROP CONSTRAINT varaus_fkey;
ALTER TABLE varaus DROP CONSTRAINT id;
```

Comment: varaus_id is the column name not the foreign key constraint name.

Comment: How to find out the foreign key constraint name?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395466 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273717

Answer (score 2):

You have to find the name of constraint first using below query -

```
select constraint_name
from information_schema.table_constraints
where table_schema = 'your_schema_name'
and table_name='varaus'
and constraint_name like 'fk_%'
```

Then use those names in below query -

```
ALTER TABLE varaus DROP CONSTRAINT constraint_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Good example of why you should always name your constraints instead letting the DBMS generate a name. So instead of the initial creation of the FK use (for example)

```
alter table  varaus add  
      constraint var2kay_fk 
      foreign key ( varaus_id ) 
      references  kayttaja  ( id );
```